# Which gas has the potential of having high content of water vapor molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, evaporation

Air can contain a certain amount of water vapor molecules.

I want to know that which any other non-hazardous gas can adsorb very more amount of water vapor molecules?

Answer (score 2):

The air is not a sponge.

The maximum amount of gaseous water in a volume is just the saturation pressure (the vapor pressure) of water.

[image]

At 100 C the curve passes 760 torr = 1 atmosphere.